# Degrees of freedom in theoretical sample variance (for use in F-distribution)

Tags: binomial-distribution, degrees-of-freedom, f-distribution

My question is essentially simple: suppose we have a sequence of heads and tails with an apparent chance of getting heads $\hat{p} = 0.5$.

> h h t h t t t h t t h ...

How do we tell if this sample was drawn from a binomial distribution with this $\hat{p}$ or if it comes from a combination of different distributions which produces the same average? (e.g. $p = 0.25$ or $p = 0.75$)

Here's what I was thinking of doing:

- We chop the sequence into subsections of length $n$, for example $n=5$, and calculate $\hat{p}$ in every such window:

  > {h h t h t}, {t t h t t}, {h ...}

  > 0.6, 0.2, ...
- We then calculate the standard deviation in these $\hat{p}$ values:
  $\sigma_{ex}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^M{(\hat{p}_i - \hat{\mu})^2}}{M}}$, where $\hat{\mu}$ is the average $\hat{p}$ and $M$ is the total number of windows of size $n$ we can make.
- We calculate the standard deviation in $\hat{p}$ based on a binomial distribution, $\sigma_{th}=\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$.

Now comes the problem: how to determine if these two values are the same? After a lot of research, I decided to try using an F-ratio test and plugging the result into an f-distribution.

F-ratio: $F = \frac{\sigma_{ex}^2}{\sigma_{th}^2}$ (only valid for normal-distributions :S)

And then an f-distribution to get to a p-value we can check against. However, for the f-distribution I need to know the degrees of freedom in the nominator and denominator. And therein lies my problem: what are the degrees of freedom for the variance calculated from theory? (In the experimental case I think it is M)

If you have this answer or any suggestions on how to solve this problem differently, I would love to hear about it!

Comment: Please do not repeatedly post your question (or minor variants of it).  For ways to bring attention to unanswered questions, please see our [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: It's not a duplicate in my opinion. The only thing I need to know is how to determine the degrees of freedom, but I decided to provide some background to make the question clearer which is indeed the same as the previous case. But actually I would not mind removing the old question if that makes you feel better because it was a bit vague perhaps.

Comment: OK: to keep the connection between the two questions apparent, I will just mark the original as a "duplicate" of this one so it links back here.